# Why am I receiving this error? This date function has worked fine in my overall script until today

Tags: python, error-handling, jupyter-notebook

I am using this date function in a python script of mine and it has been working for months. Now, as of this morning it is not working. Here is an image of the error that I receive when I try and run the function. I receive the

[error in script when running date function by itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aen5I.png)

date function that I'm using to format the date:

```
def format_date(date):
    return str(int(date[4:6]) + '/' + str(int(date[6::])) + '/' + date[0:4])
```

error that I receive after I try and run the function:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-7b46987210f9> in <module>
----> 1 format_date(20220425)

<ipython-input-18-c708fe24a649> in format_date(date)
      1 def format_date(date):
----> 2     return str(int(date[4:6]) + '/' + str(int(date[6::])) + '/' + date[0:4])

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the error that I receive when I try and run the entire script without isolating the function.

```
    return str(int(date[4:6])) + '/' + str(int(date[6::])) + '/' + date[0:4]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Do you need to put quotes around the input value (i.e. pass it as a string, not as a number)?

Comment: Please provide all your code examples and error messages as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: You provide two different errors. First define `date = 20211012` and call `int(date[4:6])`. Then define `date = ''` and call `int(date[4:6])`. Do you see where the errors comes from?

Comment: I tried to put quotes around the input value and I received TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: I would probably use `strptime` and `strftime`, something like `return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y%m%d").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is slicing an integer type `formate_date(int)`
 that's why you are getting an error.

Instead what you should do is to first convert your given parameter to string type. 
which also makes your overall code look even cleaner.

```
def format_date(date):
    date = str(date)
    return date[4:6] + '/' + date[6::] + '/' + date[0:4]

#input formate_date(20220425)
#output 04/25/2022
```

Comment: Thank you all. I appreciate your help. The answer that Shobhit provided works.